# Identity log out suddenly in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: identity, asp.net-core-7.0

I developed an application using ASP.NET Core 7. I used the identity framework for authentication. When publishing the website, users complained as it logs them out after 10 - 15 minutes. What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

I tried many things to solve yet only on my PC, it is solved, but not after publishing